# acces to the file C:\inetpub\wwwroot is denied?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed asp.net application in amazon web services elastic beanstalk. But when I try to save the files in app_data folder I am denied accessing it. How can I solve this issue.

Comment: Make sure that the application pool for the website is running and have permissions to access the directory.

Answer (score 0):

you dont have Write permission on the server folder just log in to amazon web services and change the permission of the folder where you are publishing the app to Read/write